# Nginx Rewrite URL Rule having special character(#) for Page section

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I need help in rewriting the URL in nginx configuration which should work as below :

/products/#details to /produce/#items

but it is not working as **#** is creating a problem.

Note : **#** in the URL denotes the page section

e.g. **www.test.com/products/#details** should get redirected to **www.test.com/produce/#items**

Answer (score 0):

**This is impossible using nginx** because browsers don't send hashtags (`#details`) to servers. So you cannot rewrite in nginx or any other web servers.

In other words, hashtags is available to the browser only, so you have to deal it with Javascript. The server can not read it.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-4

> When a URI reference is used to perform a retrieval action on the identified resource, the optional fragment identifier, separated from the URI by a crosshatch ("#") character, consists of additional reference information to be interpreted by the user agent after the retrieval action has been successfully completed. As such, it is not part of a URI, but is often used in conjunction with a URI.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this rewrite. The `#` and everything that precedes it will not be sent to the server, it is completely handled on the client side.